# Laminate floor directly over plywood subfloor ok?

Tags: subfloor, plywood, laminate-floor, underlayment, particle-board

We just ripped up carpet in a room and found that it had 1/2" plywood over the joists and 5/8" particle board on top of that.

We are planning to install 10mm laminate flooring in this room.  The flooring includes a pre-installed pad underneath it.

This wouldn't be an issue, but I found that the transition to the next room will create a rather large step between the two floors.  The next room is 10 mm (25/64") hardwood placed directly on the plywood.  The particle board is already taller than that, and the new floor will be 10 mm thick.

Photo below shows the view from the hardwood side of the threshold into the room that will get the new the flooring.  The stack-up will be almost 28mm high.  Transitioning 18 mm seems like a steep threshold, and maybe a tripping hazard.  Unless I make the threshold as thick as the doorway, but that won't match the rest of the house.

Can I remove the particle board and install directly over the plywood, or is that not strong enough?  I could consider installing an underlayment if it's not too thick, but I don't think that's going to be structurally relevant.

**EDIT:**   I posted [this question](http://file:///home/rothloup/Documents/Family/Relationship/Love%20Is%20Not/stupidcrap/data/local_record/keep/screenrec/screenrec%20-%20image%20download%20complete.mp4) to see if I could determine the type of floor in the adjoining room.  It is NOT solid hardwood, as I originally thought.  Now the question is whether this floor  is structurally relevant.  If it's not, or can be considered the same as the laminate I'm about to install, then I can probably expect the same structural performance out of the two floors if they are both built on the same sub-floor.  **Is that correct?**  As @Kris asked in a comment, the existing flooring on the 1/2" plywood is not bouncy.

[image]

Comment: What's the span between joists? 1/2" ply isn't much of a subfloor, but if the joists are closely spaced, it *might* work.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  16" OC spacing on the joists.  I was wondering how the other floor (installed when we moved in, likely since construction) could be installed over just the plywood.  I was hoping that meant that the plywood is enough.

Comment: Hardwood has more substance than laminate, as a rule. *i.e.* it's a finish floor, but it also has structure, unless it's run parallel to the joists.

Comment: Particle board is used because it's flat and smooth, it absorbs sounds, it absorbs impacts from walking...and it is cheap.  If you remove it, you may not like the results.

Comment: What is under the hardwood flooring?  If it is  1/2” plywood with 25/64 10mm is that floor bouncy?

Comment: @Kris it's built in the same plywood subfloor.   It's not bouncy,  but i believe that floor is real hardwood.